# Getting WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7080/query' failed on connecting graphql-ws client with gqlgen golang server

Tags: go, websocket, graphql, graphql-subscriptions, gqlgen

The subscription query listed below in code working fine on **graphql playground** but when i tried to connect my [graphql-ws](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws) client with gqlgen driven go server, i got **WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7080/query' failed** error. I tried connecting to my other localhost server running locally using **useServer function of graphql-ws** that worked nicely but got issue while connecting with go server.

Client Code:-

```
(async () => {
 const client = graphqlWs.createClient({
            url: 'ws://localhost:7080/query',
        });


 const onNext = (data) => {
          /* handle incoming values */
          console.log("data===>", data)
  };

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                unsubscribe = client.subscribe(
                    {
                        query: `subscription {
                            ping
                          }`
                       
                    },
                    {
                        next: onNext,
                        error: reject,
                        complete: resolve
                    },
                );
            });
            } catch(e) {
                console.error("E==>", e)
            }
   })();
```

Slogging since last two days to get some useful blog and link online but not found anything useful of connecting go server with vanilla js. Also searched listed issues on **graphql-ws** library on its github page but there also no such issue is listed.

Please let me know if other info is required regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

The ws subprotocol of **gqlgen** is **graphql-transport-ws** since **gqlgen@v0.15.0**. If someone is still facing connection problem at the "helloworld", check the **checkOrigin** property of websocket's upgrader.

I'm using **gqlgen@v0.17.22** and have found out that the offical example of **Websocket/Subscription** can't config the **checkOrigin** property. The problem is that the **handler.NewDefaultServer** already have a configured ws transport, we could use **handler.New** and do the rest parts ourselves.

```golang
srv := handler.New(graphql.NewSchema(client))
srv.AddTransport(transport.Options{})
srv.AddTransport(transport.GET{})
srv.AddTransport(transport.POST{})
srv.AddTransport(transport.MultipartForm{})
srv.SetQueryCache(lru.New(1000))
srv.Use(extension.Introspection{})
srv.Use(extension.AutomaticPersistedQuery{
    Cache: lru.New(100),
})
// add ws transport configured by ourselves
srv.AddTransport(&transport.Websocket{
    Upgrader: websocket.Upgrader{
        //ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        //WriteBufferSize: 1024,
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            // add checking origin logic to decide return true or false
            return true
        },
    },
    KeepAlivePingInterval: 10 * time.Second,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [this `gqlgen`](https://gqlgen.com/), it does not support the [GraphQL over WebSocket Protocol](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md) `graphql-ws` implements. [It, sadly, supports only the legacy protocol of `subscriptions-transport-ws`.](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/blob/5ad012e3d7be1127706b9c8a3da0378df3a98ec1/graphql/handler/transport/websocket.go#L65) (which is why `graphql-playground` works). Meaning, you must use the [`subscriptions-transport-ws`](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws) with their backend.

Comment: yeah i have used this gqlgen only but here in L65 of above github link it's written this `"Sec-Websocket-Protocol": []string{"graphql-ws"},` so here it's mentioned graphql-ws. Am i understanding something wrong. So, what the meaning of this line `"Sec-Websocket-Protocol": []string{"graphql-ws"},`

Comment: The subprotocol of [the new GraphQL over WebSocket is `graphql-transport-ws`](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md#communication), not `graphql-ws` (which belongs to `subscriptions-transport-ws`).